# can't pay with undefined currency in facebook Local Currency Payments

Tags: facebook, local, payment, currency

my app product defined USD,and not defined GBP.when I use GBP to pay, the pay dialog return 
the error that Sorry, there was a problem and we can’t complete your request. Please try again later.
I'm confusion about that,the facebook offical doucument show that  If you do not define a price point for a particular local currency, users of that currency will have their price automatically calculated based upon the current exchange rate between the first currency you specify and that target currency.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have just encountered this too...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you were trying 0.01 USD? that converts to less than 0.01 GBP

Defining a single unit of in-game currency that has a product:price:amount less than 0.01. For example, selling 1,000 Coins for USD 1.00 would require a unit price of 0.001, which is not supported.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/definingproducts/#pricing_static